# Qual é a diferença entre os tipos de binding no Angular?

Tags: angularjs, binding

No Angular (não AngularJS) existem algumas formas de fazer o binding de propriedades do Component para a View.

```
<img src="{{ boundProperty }}">
<img bind-src="boundProperty">
<img [src]="boundProperty">
```

Existe uma maneira correta de realizar os bindings? Em que situações cada um dos itens citados deveria ser utilizado e por quê?

Comment: Se você ler essa parte da documentação, te responderá tuas dúvidas:
 https://angular.io/guide/architecture#data-binding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não existe uma maneira correta de realizar Data Binding, cada situação pode ser usada da forma como quiser e/ou conseguir aplicar. São 4 formas:

1. Interpolação: `{{ valor }}`

   - associa informação do componente para o template (HTML)
2. Property Binding: `[propriedade]="valor"`

   - associa informação do componente para o template (HTML)
3. Event Binding: `(evento)="handler"`

   - associa informação do template (HTML) para o componente
4. Two-Way Data Binding: `[(ngModel)]="propriedade"`

   - associa informação entre ambos, ou seja, mantém ambos atualizados (componente e template (HTML).

Fonte: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlVxG2lG1Tk&list=PLGxZ4Rq3BOBoSRcKWEdQACbUCNWLczg2G&index=10